# Additional languages in Virtual XP mode under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Is there any way to get additional languages in Virtual XP Mode under Windows 7?

Thanks,

kreb

Comment: Additional languages for what? Do you mean have VM thats running Windows XP in additional languages?

Comment: Sounds like this belongs on superuser

Comment: It possibly does belong on SU but that's still not live yet so its not an option, and Virtual XP mode may be interesting to a lot of developers.

Comment: What's superuser? @mark, yes, Virtual XP specifically, as implemented in Windows 7 RC. In Win7, you can download a file (msi) that installs Windows XP SP3 as a virtual machine with VirtualPC.. I had initial problems because I didn't install XP from CD or DVD media, because I used the one from MS' website..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, for the interest..

Anyway, I managed to make it work by inserting a physical Windows XP CD (Simplified Chinese, SP2) in and getting the language files from that. WinXP complains that the files are the wrong version though and that they're not the ones used by the install media, which in this case is an MSI that I got from the Microsoft website. So yeah, just ignore the warnings, reboot, you should be good.. :)

Answer (score 0):

From my testing of XP mode it appears that its just a VM running on Windows Virtual PC where the VM add-ons provide hooks for Windows 7 to run any application that's installed on the VM. The key thing appears to be Windows Virtual PC and the add-ons, since you can have Windows 7 installed on the VM just as easily as XP.

I don't see why you couldn't have multiple VMs running different languages if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't wanna go this route as it would entail me having to download a different msi (over 400mb), and is a waste of space.. But yeah, it IS a valid option..